# How to preview any file in Lion?

Tags: preview

I love OS X Lion's feature to preview some files without opening them. Is there a way to register new file extension? For example, Drupal module extension ".module", which is a text file.

Answer (score 3):

To preview files, you need a QuickLook plugin. Special thanks to [Jason Salaz](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/1346/jason-salaz) for providing this list:

- [QuickLook Plugins List](http://www.quicklookplugins.com/)
- [QLPLugins.com](http://www.qlplugins.com/)
- [And Jason's specially crafted Google search.](http://www.google.com/search?q=quick%20look%20plugins%20drupal%20module)

It looks like there is support for the Drupal .module via [this plugin](http://realityloop.com/blog/2011/04/25/quicklook-syntax-highlighter-drupal-files-module-profile-theme-install-inc).

Comment: QLPlugins.com domain is expired.